# How to hide Info Mode Header Line in Emacs ?

Tags: emacs

I am trying to read some info manuals in Emacs , and there is Prev Next Up showing up all the time . 
Does anyone  know how to remove it ?  I tried a few things mentioned in this link , but it doesn't help .

```
(setq info-use-header-line nil) 
M-x info-header-node
(setq info-header-line nil)
```

**www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/.../info/Emacs-Info-Variables.html‎**

I prefer a cleaner display when reading Info format books for example . Using 24.3 Emacs.

Comment: I am reading a texi file ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kill the info buffer and start a new one after changing that.
It only takes effect at buffer creation time.
Also: Info-use-header-line (case matters).

Comment: Thanks thats correct !  For others M-x customiz-variable RET Info-use-header-line RET - set it to off  or ... (setq mode-line-format nil) (setq Info-use-header-line nil) alternatively to remove mode-line also